# Easiest way to loop through a filtered list with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

If I have an auto filter set up in Excel and I want to loop through all the visible data in one column with VBA code, what's the easiest way to do this?

All the hidden rows that have been filtered away should not be included, so a plain Range from top to bottom doesn't help.

Any good ideas?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Suppose I have numbers 1 to 10 in cells `A2:A11` with my autofilter in `A1`. I now filter to only show numbers greater than 5 (i.e. 6, 7, 8, 9, 10).

This code will only print visible cells:

```
Sub SpecialLoop()
    Dim cl As Range, rng As Range
    
    Set rng = Range("A2:A11")
    
    For Each cl In rng
        If cl.EntireRow.Hidden = False Then //Use Hidden property to check if filtered or not
            Debug.Print cl
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Perhaps there is a better way with `SpecialCells` but the above worked for me in Excel 2003.

**EDIT**

Just found a better way with `SpecialCells`:

```
Sub SpecialLoop()
    Dim cl As Range, rng As Range
    
    Set rng = Range("A2:A11")
    
    For Each cl In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        Debug.Print cl
    Next cl

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for all the answers! They were all more or less the same (using SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) was the key I needed) so it's hard to pick which answer is right.

Comment: use ```Debug.Print cl.row``` to get the row number or ```cl.address```

Comment: **Caution** If you have hidden columns in the range then `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` returns data that might start at the first column, or the column after the hidden ones.

Answer (score 18):

I would recommend using `Offset` assuming that the Headers are in Row 1. See this example

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim rRange As Range, filRange As Range, Rng as Range
    'Remove any filters
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False

    '~~> Set your range
    Set rRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:E10")

    With rRange
        '~~> Set your criteria and filter
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=1"

        '~~> Filter, offset(to exclude headers)
        Set filRange = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow

        Debug.Print filRange.Address

        For Each Rng In filRange
            '~~> Your Code
        Next
    End With

    'Remove any filters
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: This is a nice way of solving the problem. I like your approach.

Comment: Good solution Sid. However, I would be very careful while using `SpecialCells`. I recently faced an issue because of the way Excel sends out the `.Address` of these cells (based on their continuous appearances).

Comment: @PankajJaju: I am sorry I didn't get you. Could you please explain what do yo mean? perhaps with an example?

Comment: @SiddharthRout - If you traverse the Address of the special cells (lets say on Column A), then it would give you address like $A1, $A3:$A5, $A7, $A10:$A15 and so on. Notice that if the visible rows are continuous, they are shown as continuous range like $A10:$A15 else they would be individual cells like $A1, $A7 etc.

Comment: So if you are spliting the addresses in your programming logic, you need to be careful about this. Thats all... and this was the exact reason why my code was failing as I overlooked this fact

Comment: @PankajJaju: Oh That :) Of Course I am aware of that :)

Comment: I'm facing a "run-time error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error" on line Set filRange = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow. The only difference of the code above is that my range is .Range("A:J")

Comment: I need a filter AND index-based access to 2 columns, so `for each` probably does not work. Do I need [autofilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofilter) or can I use `xlcelltypevisible`?

Comment: @Timo: Not usre what do you mean. Can you elaborate on it? Or Perhaps ask a new question with more details?

Answer (score 11):

One way assuming filtered data in A1 downwards;

```
dim Rng as Range
set Rng = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
...
for each cell in Rng 
   ...
```

Answer (score 2):

I used the `RowHeight` property of a range (which means cells as well). If it's zero then it's hidden.
So just loop through all rows as you would normally but in the `if` condition check for that property as in `If myRange.RowHeight > 0 then DoStuff` where `DoStuff` is something you want to do with the visible cells.

Answer (score 0):

The SpecialCells Does not actually work as it needs to be continuous. I have solved this by adding a sort funtion in order to sort the data based on the coloumns i need.

Sorry for no comments on the code as i was not planning to share it:

```
Sub testtt()
    arr = FilterAndGetData(Worksheets("Data").range("A:K"), Array(1, 9), Array("george", "WeeklyCash"), Array(1, 2, 3, 10, 11), 1)
    Debug.Print sms(arr)
End Sub
Function FilterAndGetData(ByVal rng As Variant, ByVal fields As Variant, ByVal criterias As Variant, ByVal colstoreturn As Variant, ByVal headers As Boolean) As Variant
Dim SUset, EAset, CMset
If Application.ScreenUpdating Then Application.ScreenUpdating = False: SUset = False Else SUset = True
If Application.EnableEvents Then Application.EnableEvents = False: EAset = False Else EAset = True
If Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic Then Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual: CMset = False Else CMset = True
For Each col In rng.Columns: col.Hidden = False: Next col

Dim oldsheet, scol, ecol, srow, hyesno As String
Dim i, counter As Integer

oldsheet = ActiveSheet.Name


Worksheets(rng.Worksheet.Name).Activate

Worksheets(rng.Worksheet.Name).AutoFilterMode = False

scol = Chr(rng.Column + 64)
ecol = Chr(rng.Columns.Count + rng.Column + 64 - 1)
srow = rng.row

If UBound(fields) - LBound(fields) <> UBound(criterias) - LBound(criterias) Then FilterAndGetData = "Fields&Crit. counts dont match": GoTo done

dd = sortrange(rng, colstoreturn, headers)

For i = LBound(fields) To UBound(fields)
    rng.AutoFilter Field:=CStr(fields(i)), Criteria1:=CStr(criterias(i))
Next i

Dim rngg As Variant

rngg = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
Debug.Print ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.range.address
FilterAndGetData = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value

For Each row In rng.Rows
    If row.EntireRow.Hidden Then Debug.Print yes
Next row


done:
    'Worksheets("Data").AutoFilterMode = False
    Worksheets(oldsheet).Activate
    If SUset Then Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    If EAset Then Application.EnableEvents = True
    If CMset Then Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Function
Function sortrange(ByVal rng As Variant, ByVal colnumbers As Variant, ByVal headers As Boolean)

    Dim SUset, EAset, CMset
    If Application.ScreenUpdating Then Application.ScreenUpdating = False: SUset = False Else SUset = True
    If Application.EnableEvents Then Application.EnableEvents = False: EAset = False Else EAset = True
    If Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic Then Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual: CMset = False Else CMset = True
    For Each col In rng.Columns: col.Hidden = False: Next col

    Dim oldsheet, scol, srow, sortcol, hyesno As String
    Dim i, counter As Integer
    oldsheet = ActiveSheet.Name
    Worksheets(rng.Worksheet.Name).Activate
    Worksheets(rng.Worksheet.Name).AutoFilterMode = False
    scol = rng.Column
    srow = rng.row

    If headers Then hyesno = xlYes Else hyesno = xlNo

    For i = LBound(colnumbers) To UBound(colnumbers)
        rng.Sort key1:=range(Chr(scol + colnumbers(i) + 63) + CStr(srow)), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=hyesno
    Next i
    sortrange = "123"
done:
    Worksheets(oldsheet).Activate
    If SUset Then Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    If EAset Then Application.EnableEvents = True
    If CMset Then Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = 2
x = 0

Do Until Cells(a, 1).Value = ""
If Rows(a).Hidden = False Then
x = Cells(a, 1).Value + x
End If
a = a + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

```
Thisworkbook.sheets("Mysheet").Range("A1).Currentregion.copy 
Thisworkbook.sheets("Othersheet").Range("A1)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please check out [How to Write a Good Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and include necessary details to address the question

Answer (score -1):

```
Call MyMacro()

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate

Do Until Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
If Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True Then
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
End If
Loop
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide some explanation what the code do.