# filter table in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

New to excel vba, Sorry if this is too obvious...

 I got this data in spreadsheet, 

 How can filter out the table by "title" column 

 So I will be able to select part of the table by filtered by title

 thanks

```
book name       Description                             title
gsod        Samples from US weather since 1929          title1
mlab        Measurement data of performance             title1
natality    Birth States from 1969 to 2008              title2
shakespeare Word index for works of                     title2
wikipedia   Revision information for Wikipedia          title1
```

Comment: what version of Excel are you using? In Excel2007 and 2010 you can just select the data and 'Format as a Table', after that the headers get a triangle next to them which you can click to filter

Comment: Its 2010, trying to do this programatically ... Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple example to accomplish what you are trying to do is:

```
Sub SortColumnC()

If Sheets(1).AutoFilterMode = False Then
    Sheets(1).Range("A1:C1").AutoFilter
End If

RowCount = Sheets(1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C2:C" & RowCount), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).AutoFilter.Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I Have found a working solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849177/easiest-way-to-loop-through-a-filtered-list-with-vba