# How to select and paste values in filtered cells in Excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Please see below picture in which a filter is applied in column a to choose Item "b" and then updated "OK" in comment field. Do you have any idea how this can be done through macro?  Also, I need to know how to select the visible cells in a column when a filter is on and filtered.

[image]

Comment: Autofilter: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221844(v=office.11).aspx

Selecting filtered cells: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849177/easiest-way-to-loop-through-a-filtered-list-with-vba

Comment: This is for selecting the cells. My question is how to select a cell just below the header line, say "B4" directlty from A1, then comment it "OK". Likewise it should repeat for B5,B9,B10

Comment: You'll need to use Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) as shown in many examples in the second link.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub Copy_Filtered_Cells()
Set from = Application.InputBox("Select range of Cell to copy", Type:=8).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
'Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
'Set from = Selection
Set too = Application.InputBox("Select range to Paste Copied Cells", Type:=8)
For Each Cell In from
    Cell.Copy
    For Each thing In too
        If thing.EntireRow.RowHeight > 0 Then
            thing.PasteSpecial
            Set too = thing.Offset(1).Resize(too.Rows.Count)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

it might work for you.