# How can I loop through rows in excel using VBA if rows are sorted so row numbers aren't consecutive

Tags: excel, vba, loops, rows

I am trying to loop through the rows in an excel spreadsheet using VBA, only concerning myself with the data in column 17 (hence the Cells(i,17).Value). I want to loop through the rows in column 17, then loop through the individual characters in that specific cell, checking if they contain a number or a full stop. If they do, I want to add them to a variable num, then once I have looped through the cell and reached the end, I want to replace the cell's contents with that stored in the num variable. I then go to the next row down and repeat until looping through all the rows. I believe my code so far will do this.

However, I have realized I am hitting problems with this due to the way I am looping through rows. The rows I am looping through are not consecutively numbered so my for loop starts with row 1 then 2 etc. This is causing problems because the data I have to loop through is not consecutively numbered so row numbers are:

1, 182, 477, 480, 620 etc. They are physically one below the other but not numerically so I am struggling with how to loop through rows that don't have consecutive row numbers.

Sorry that was very wordy, this is my first question on this forum and your help would be very appreciated, I'm also new to Visual Basic so sorry if my response seems silly.

Below is the code I have so far:

```
LastRow = Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row

For i = 1 To LastRow

If Cells(i, 17).Value <> "Remaining Labor Units" Then

    For CharCellCount = 1 To Len(Cells(i, 17).Value)
        char = Mid(Cells(i, 17), CharCellCount, 1)

        If char Like "[0-9]" Then
            num = num + char

        ElseIf char Like "." Then
            num = num + char
        End If

        If CharCellCount = Len(Cells(i, 17).Value) Then
            CharCellCount = 0
            Cells(i, 17).Value = num
            num = 0
        End If
    Next CharCellCount

ElseIf Cells(i, 17).Value = "Remaining Labor Units" Then
    Cells(i, 17).Value = "Remaining Labor Units"

End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Why not sorting your data before looping ? You can re-sort it in the original order when you're done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making an assumption that you in fact have a filtered list which at present state only returns rows 1, 182, 477, 480, 620 and so on, in that case you can change you `for` line to the following:

```
For Each cell In Range(Cells(1, 17), Cells(Rows.Count, 17).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

in this case you also need to change your references i.e. `cells(i, 17).value` to just `cell.value`
and also change `next i` to just `next`

Comment: Thanks that worked great! Slightly different question but if I want to then set the value of my cell to equal the values stored in the num variable, how do I do that? I am doing cell.Value = num but it doesn't seem to be doing anything

Comment: hm... seems to be working ok for me on some mock data. what is "num" declared as?

Comment: Making another assumption it is undeclared. Declare it as `Dim num as String`and then reset it by using `num = ""`rather than `num = 0`

Comment: num is delcared as a String, and I changed it to be num = empty instead, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Are the other rows hidden? In that case you could use the code below. I've implemented the property:

```
rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

This code sets the range to the cells that are visible.

I've found the solution here: [Easiest way to loop through a filtered list with VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849177/easiest-way-to-loop-through-a-filtered-list-with-vba)

```
    Public Sub test()
Dim i As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim LastRow As Integer

LastRow = Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row

Set rng = Range("A1:A" & LastRow)

For Each i In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

If Cells(i, 17).Value <> "Remaining Labor Units" Then

    For CharCellCount = 1 To Len(Cells(i, 17).Value)
        char = Mid(Cells(i, 17), CharCellCount, 1)

        If char Like "[0-9]" Then
            num = num + char

        ElseIf char Like "." Then
            num = num + char
        End If

        If CharCellCount = Len(Cells(i, 17).Value) Then
            CharCellCount = 0
            Cells(i, 17).Value = num
            num = 0
        End If
    Next CharCellCount

ElseIf Cells(i, 17).Value = "Remaining Labor Units" Then
    Cells(i, 17).Value = "Remaining Labor Units"

End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Wouter