# Loop through filtered values in excel

Tags: vbscript, excel-2007

I am trying to automatically apply filter on a column in the excel sheet and I have to loop through the filtered values available on different column.I am not getting how to loop through the filtered values?

Applying filter on 19th column.Have to loop through the values available on 12th column.

```
  strPath="C:\Users\PSi\Desktop\CodeIn.xlsx"

    Dim ProcessName

    ProcessName=Trim(InputBox("Process Name:"))
    Set objExcel= CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    objExcel.Visible= True

    objExcel.Workbooks.Open(strPath)

    With objExcel.Activeworkbook.Sheets("All")

        .Range("A1").AutoFilter 19,"="&ProcessName

    End With
    'How to loop through the filtered values ??
    'Need to loop through only on the above filtered values..
     for i=2 to (How to get end of filtered used rows)

if Mid(objExcel.Activeworkbook.Sheets("All").Cells(i,12).Value,1,3)="Seq" 
    Then msgbox objExcel.Activeworkbook.Sheets("All").Cells(i,12).Value
End if
      Next
```

Comment: Please try the past post maybe it will help you [Click Me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849177/easiest-way-to-loop-through-a-filtered-list-with-vba)

Comment: use `Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`

Comment: Can you please help me here? How can I use this in my current code?