# Having VBA Macro Work With Filtering

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that works on an entire worksheet, including data that has been hidden by filtering. How can I go about having my code only apply to data that is showing after a filter is applied?

Comment: Help us to help you.....post more details

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849177/easiest-way-to-loop-through-a-filtered-list-with-vba

Comment: @munircontractor posted a link that helped me, thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

`SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`