# How to loop Excel cells Filter

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have a column that I want to Filter values:

[image]

Now I want to loop only on filtered cells
This is what i have done:

```
For lin = 2 to lastLine    
    If Not Plan11.Cells(lin, 1).Hidden Then
          //do something
    End If
Next
```

But I have more than 50000 cells... is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: There is a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849177/easiest-way-to-loop-through-a-filtered-list-with-vba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `SpecialCells` method of the `range` object

```
with ws.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
'... do something.
'    for instance:  .Font.Bold = True
end with
```

where `ws` is the worksheet object whose column "A" you want to work with

Answer (score 1):

You can find filtered cells using:

```
ActiveSheet.range("valid range for column").Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

Then you can iterate on result and do stuff.

For example, When I have a table I can do it this way:

```
Dim lastRow
lastRow = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").range.Rows.Count
Dim range
Set range = ActiveSheet.range("A2:A" & lastRow).Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
For Each rCell In range.Cells
    MsgBox rCell.Value
Next rCell
```