# Get Excel filter results into VBA array

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I have a VBA subroutine which filters records that have the text "SV-PCS7" in column 4. How can I get these results into an array?

```
Sub FilterTo1Criteria()
Dim xlbook As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlsheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim ro As Integer
Set xlbook = GetObject("C:\07509\04-LB-06 MX-sv.xlsx")
Set xlsheet = xlbook.Sheets("04-LB-06 MX")
   With xlsheet

       .AutoFilterMode = False
       .Range("blockn").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="SV-PCS7"

   End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid the complex looping of Jeeped's (excellent) solution, you can use a temp sheet to copy the visible rows first.

```
Sub test()
    Dim src As Range, m As Variant, sh As Worksheet

    Set src = Sheet1.Range("c3").CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Set sh = Worksheets.Add

    src.Copy sh.Range("a1")
    m = sh.Range("a1").CurrentRegion
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    sh.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Debug.Print UBound(m)
End Sub
```

Comment: The temp sheet solution works well. When it gets to the point of deleting the sheet, it switches to Excel for confirmation. Could I disable this (either in the code or in Excel)

Comment: @tmccar Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Answer (score 3):

After applying the [Range.AutoFilter Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193884.aspx) and determining that there are visible cells, you need to work through the [Range.Areas property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196243.aspx) of the [Range.SpecialCells method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx) with xlCellTypeVisible. Each of the areas will have one or more rows to process.

```
Sub FilterTo1Criteria()
    Dim a As Long, r As Long, c As Long, vals As Variant
    Dim xlSheet As Worksheet
    'Set xlbook = GetObject("C:\07509\04-LB-06 MX-sv.xlsx")
    Set xlSheet = Worksheets("04-LB-06 MX")
    With xlSheet
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False

        'With .Range("blockn")
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="SV-PCS7"
            'step off the header row
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)
                'check if there are visible cells
                If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then
                    'dimension the array (backwards)
                    ReDim vals(1 To .Columns.Count, 1 To 1)
                    'loop through the areas
                    For a = 1 To .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas.Count
                        With .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas(a)
                            'loop through the rows in each area
                            For r = 1 To .Rows.Count
                                'put the call values in backwards because we cannot redim the 'row'
                                For c = LBound(vals, 1) To UBound(vals, 1)
                                    vals(c, UBound(vals, 2)) = .Cells(r, c).Value
                                Next c
                                'make room for the next
                                ReDim Preserve vals(1 To UBound(vals, 1), 1 To UBound(vals, 2) + 1)
                            Next r
                        End With
                    Next a
                End If
            End With
        End With

        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With


    'trim off the last empty 'row'
    ReDim Preserve vals(1 To UBound(vals, 1), 1 To UBound(vals, 2) - 1)
    'reorient the array
    vals = Application.Transpose(vals)
    'show the extents
    Debug.Print LBound(vals, 1) & ":" & UBound(vals, 1)
    Debug.Print LBound(vals, 2) & ":" & UBound(vals, 2)

    'show the values
    For r = LBound(vals, 1) To UBound(vals, 1)
        For c = LBound(vals, 2) To UBound(vals, 2)
            Debug.Print vals(r, c)
        Next c
    Next r

End Sub
```

The **Preserve** option can be used with the [ReDim statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8k3cys2.aspx) but only the last range can be redimensioned. I've built the array in the wrong orientation and then used the [TRANSPOSE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TRANSPOSE-function-ED039415-ED8A-4A81-93E9-4B6DFAC76027) to flip the orientation. Note: there are limits to the amount of array elements that can be successfully flipped.

Comment: It's breaking down at this line:                                                                                                                   "If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then"   with runtime error 438  - Object doesn't support this property or method".   Maybe this function is  not available in VBA for Autocad?

Comment: It's breaking down at the application object. You might try something like `If CBool(xlbook.Subtotal(103, .Cells))` Then` but I don't have VBA for Autocad to test on.

Comment: in Autocad VBA use "ExcelApp.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells))" where "ExcelApp" is the name of the variable you set Excel Application object to

Comment: Jeeped, I've got a bit further with your code but it now stops with error 13-type mismatch" at line   "ReDim Preserve vals(1 To UBound(vals, 1), 1 To UBound(vals, 2) - 1)"

Comment: As I do not have VBA for AutoCAD, I would suggest running through the sub procedure completely within Excel and its own native VBA. When that works, run it through VBA for AutoCAD and use the documentation to make substitutions in the code.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the best way to do it is looping through each row, checking to see if the row is hidden (`cell.EntireRow.Hidden = False`), and adding the data for that row into the array if it's not hidden. Similar example: [Easiest way to loop through a filtered list with VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849177/easiest-way-to-loop-through-a-filtered-list-with-vba)