# Excel file running in background and while accessing to other excel file , the main excel file data is coming

Tags: c#, excel

There is no error in the code , but I'm stuck with the excel file. I have used 2 excel files, one is `abc30` and other is `abc31`. `abc30` is filtered and saved as `abc31`, now I want to access `abc31`, but again `abc30` data is coming here. Please check the code and let me know the problem.

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace ExcelCalculation
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // button click 
        private void bindingbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {                   
            Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
            //ApplicationClass excelApplication = null;
            Workbook excelWorkBook = null;
            Worksheet targetSheet = null;
            // Excel.Range salesTable=null ;

            // Declare helper variables.  
            string workBookName = @"E:\Sample\abc30.xlsx";
            string worksheetName = "DATA";

            object useDefault = Type.Missing;

            // Open the source workbook.
            excelWorkBook =
                excelApp.Workbooks.Open(workBookName,
                    useDefault, useDefault, useDefault, useDefault,
                    useDefault, useDefault, useDefault, useDefault,
                    useDefault, useDefault, useDefault, useDefault,
                    useDefault, useDefault);


            string[] listFilter = new string[] { "abc, def (11)", "df, df (1111)", "Md, At (1388)", "Gho, Sram (183)" };

            // Get the worksheet that contains the data to filter.
            targetSheet =
                (Worksheet)(excelWorkBook.Worksheets[worksheetName]);


            Excel.Range range = targetSheet.UsedRange;
            range.AutoFilter(18, "open", Excel.XlAutoFilterOperator.xlAnd, Type.Missing, true);
            range.AutoFilter(26, "saS", Excel.XlAutoFilterOperator.xlAnd, Type.Missing, true);
            range.AutoFilter(23, "abcd", Excel.XlAutoFilterOperator.xlAnd, Type.Missing, true);

            foreach (string abc in listFilter)
            {
                range.AutoFilter(27, listFilter, Excel.XlAutoFilterOperator.xlFilterValues, Type.Missing, true);
            }
            Excel.Range filteredRange = range.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible);
             excelApp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(@"E:\Sample\abc31.xlsx");

            excelWorkBook.Close(true, null, null);
            excelApp.Quit();
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(targetSheet);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelWorkBook);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelApp);

            FirstColumn(@"E:\Sample\abc31.xlsx");
        }

        // Firstcolumn (filename) method ,here i'm getting error
        public static string[] FirstColumn(string filename)
        {
//Here in this method , I'm not getting the data what i need , 
//i'm getting from main excel file data .please let me know where i'm wrong.

            Excel.Application excelApp1 = new Excel.Application();
            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(filename);
            fileInfo.IsReadOnly = false;

            if (excelApp1 == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("EXCEL could not be started. Check that your office installation and project references are correct.");
                return null;
            }
            Workbook wb = excelApp1.Workbooks.Open(filename,
                0, false, 5, "", "", false, XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true);
            //wb.Path = filename;
            Sheets sheets = wb.Worksheets;
            Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)sheets.get_Item("DATA");
// getting 19th column 
            Range firstColumn = ws.UsedRange.Columns[19];
            System.Array myvalues = (System.Array)firstColumn.Cells.Value;
            string[] strArray = myvalues.OfType<object>().Select(o => o.ToString()).ToArray();
            return strArray;
//return array will be  having data from main excel i.e abc30, but (string filename - abc31 )has only filtered data , i need that data , please help me out .
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Its a filter.. all the data in file30 is still there because its only a filter.. if you want to remove the data then you would do best to copy out on the data you need to the new one.

Comment: Hi , when  i filtered the data and saved it shows only 10 data out of 1000 . so i saved 10 data in abc31 file and then only i'm trying to accessing it .

Comment: No you didnt, you saved 1000 lines of data, because a filter is just that, just cos you see 10 the other 990 are still there. as proved by the results you are getting

Comment: Okay then i need  copy the filtered data  right .Any easy method to do it please .

Answer (score 0):

You should check just for non-hidden cells (or use Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) method). See [Easiest way to loop through a filtered list with VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849177/easiest-way-to-loop-through-a-filtered-list-with-vba)

Comment: Hi Milan , Thanks for your response .

Comment: When i run my application , excel file getting the data from first file i.e abc30 and i want the data from abc31 , how can i do that in C#.i have tried different methods , but still i'm failing to get data . please check it and try to give me solution

Comment: How do you know that Excel is returning data from abc30.xlsx file? What you get if you read `wb.FullName` property inside `FirstColumn` method?

Comment: FullName = {System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Old format or invalid type library. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80028018 (TYPE_E_INVDATAREAD))
   --- E...

Comment: Hi actually abc30 has 1000 data and abc31 has only 10 data , so when i see the data in debug mode i get to know that.

Comment: That strange - Workbook has a property FullName. But still - how do you know data are read from abc30.xlsx? How you prove that?

Comment: You mean that you can see just 10 rows of data in abc31.xlsx? But that's ok. Note, that all rows are still present in abc31.xlsx because you just filtered them out (try set filter to all and you can see all rows). Applying filter means "hide all non-matching rows".

Comment: string[] strArray = myvalues.OfType<object>().Select(o => o.ToString()).ToArray();

Comment: There i can see the data sir , then i get to know its from abc30

Comment: I bet it comes from abc31.xlsx. You just can't see the difference using this approach. Just try to iterate through all rows and filter out all hidden. Something like `Range firstColumn = ws.UsedRange.Columns[19].SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible);`