# Delete Multiple Rows from Table

Tags: excel, excel-2013

Currently running Excel 2013.  My spreadsheet recently became a table, and it has a few thousand rows of data.  Before I was filtering by a date range then deleting certain rows, and I was using Find & Select->Go To Special->Visible cells only to select all the visible cells and not removed the rows that were filtered out.

Apparently I can't delete multiple rows as a table, is there a way around this?  The option is grayed out, the shortcut ctrl+- doesn't work, I've tried changing a regedit key as per a previous thread.

Is my tragic fate to copy the information into a non-table sheet, edit, copy back to original and reformat as a table?  Please tell me it isn't so.

[screen crop of the grayed out option after selecting 'visible cells only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWuZ2.png)

Comment: Loop through the areas of SpecialCells(xlCellsTypeVisible) and inner loop through each row in each area. Collect rows into a union then delete the union.

Comment: So there's no way to make a simple change in the ribbon/right-click, it has to be a VBA macro?
I'm not too familiar with SpecialCells and looping, nor unions.  Would [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849177/easiest-way-to-loop-through-a-filtered-list-with-vba) help with the looping or am I way off base?

I've also added an image to help narrow down what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

- Left clicking on the row number on the left side of the screen selects the whole row. After that, a right click on the row number brings up a menu where you can click delete.
- Multiple rows can be selected by holding down ctrl or holding down shift while clicking on row numbers. Then a right click on any of the row numbers and click delete should remove all the selected rows.
- Sorting the table can make selecting multiple rows easier.

Comment: You can't do this in a table in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

This will help

```
Private Sub imperecheaza_Click() {
 Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim Rand As Long
  Set ws = Worksheets("BD_IR")    
  Rand = 3
   Do While ws.Cells(Rand, 4).Value <> "" And Rand < 65000
   If ws.Cells(Rand, 4).Value = gksluri.Value * 1 And ws.Cells(Rand, 5).Value = gksluri.List(gksluri.ListIndex, 1) * 1 Then
     ws.Rows(Rand) = ""    '(here you will delete entire Row)
     gksluri.RemoveItem gksluri.ListIndex
     Exit Do
     End If
   Rand = Rand + 1
  Loop
 End Sub
```