# Receiving type mismatch when using Case statement for only visible cells

Tags: vba, excel

I'm receiving an error at the bold line regarding a type mismatch. 
The Case statement refers to a cell value that's only visible but I'm not sure if the Case statement is able to read the value of the cell sorted by visibility.

The function is to sort through the cells to match the `CHART ID` and insert the set of data associated with it when the search matches, if it doesn't the codes will look to check if the cell it's on is empty.

If the cell is not empty, the code will move to the next cell by incrementing k by 1 and continue to attempt to insert the data by subtracting n by 1 so that it'll run the data through the next cell.

this is looped til all the counts in the variable (e.g `Wet_etch`) is inserted into the chart before continuing to do so for `EXPOSE` and `PI_CURE` (Which I've yet to code til I've completed `WET_Etch`.

Do ask if I have to verify the vales that are obtained while running the code.

```
    Function SetData(WET_ETCH, EXPOSE, PI_CURE As Long)

    Dim n, k As Integer

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set sh(1) = Sheets("Data_Wet Etch")
    Set sh(2) = Sheets("Data_EXPOSE")
    Set sh(3) = Sheets("Data_PI CURE")

    ws.Activate

    'Clear filter
    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
        On Error Resume Next
        ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
        On Error GoTo 0

      ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$J$63") _
    .AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=RGB(255, 0 _
    , 0), Operator:=xlFilterFontColor

     ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$J$63") _
    .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="WET ETCH", Operator:=xlFilterValues




    'Loop through count of Wet_Etch
    For n = 1 To WET_ETCH

            'To loop through available data columns for input
            k = 1
            If k <= 7 Then

                    'Check cells for chart ID to set data or insert new data
                    'Code to set case as only visible rows on sheet
                    Select Case ws.Range("D" & n + 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                    ***Case Is = sh(1).Range("B" & 84 + k)***

                        'Set PPK value
                        sh(1).Range("T" & 84 + k) = _
                        ws.Range("H" & n + 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

                    'Check for empty line and inserts chart title
                    Case Is = ws.Range("B" & 83 + k) = ""

                        'Set PPK value
                        sh(1).Range("T" & 83 + k) = _
                        ws.Range("H" & n + 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                        'Set Chart ID
                        sh(1).Range("B" & 83 + k) = _
                        ws.Range("D" & n + 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

                    Case Else
                    k = k + 1
                    n = n - 1
                    End Select
            End If
     Next n

            'Clear filter
            If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
                On Error Resume Next
                ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
                On Error GoTo 0


End Function
```

Comment: you need to use `.Value` to compare the values of the cell. `ws.Range("D" & n + 1).Value` and then `Case sh(1).Range("B" & 84 + k).Value`. Another thing is that `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` doesn't make any sense here because `ws.Range("D" & n + 1)` is exactly one cell. `.SpecialCells` is to select e.g. only visible cells out of a range of cells. To check if a single cell is visible use `If ws.Range("D" & n + 1).Hidden Then …`

Comment: Well I'm having the issue of not knowing how to compare the cell 'Case sh(1).Range("B" & 84 + k).Value' to a post filtered cell that I was hoping to be able to identify through declaring that I was only looking through visible cells. 

How would I be able to implement the comparison given that I'm attempting to compare through the visible cells after filtering?

Comment: Have a look here: [Easiest way to loop through a filtered list with VBA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849177/easiest-way-to-loop-through-a-filtered-list-with-vba)