# VBA: Paste visible cells (filtered) into same rows but another column

Tags: excel, vba, filter, copy, paste

I was wondering how to paste filtered data into the same corresponding rows but another column.

I have a filtered Table in Excel like this:

```
#Row    |      A      |     B
 1      |      foo    |  
 5      |      bar    | 
 8      |      fish   |
```

Now I want to paste values from Column A into B maintaining the row position.

```
#Row    |     A       |     B
 1      |     foo     |     foo
 2      |             |
 3      |             | 
 4      |             |
 5      |     bar     |     bar 
 ...    |             |
 ...    |             |
 8      |    fish     |     fish
```

the normal paste method pastes the values as a consecutive block.

```
last = db_ws.Rows(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
db_ws.Range("A11:BC" & last).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
tgt_ws.Range("A11").PasteSpecial
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You want to use a loop over the visible cells and store the row as a variable: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849177/easiest-way-to-loop-through-a-filtered-list-with-vba  .

Comment: Are you pasting onto a different worksheet, as the two worksheet variables `db_ws` and `tgt_ws` suggest?

Comment: Thanks for your respone Emily. I just recognized that looping is probably the only solution here.

Comment: @BigBen Hi, ah sorry the code here is unclear. Actually before copying in Sheet `tgt_ws` I want to do a archive/history for the filtered values in column A and paste them into the same sheet `db_ws` in column BC

Comment: Got it, that additional detail is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code snippet:

```
Dim i as Long
last = db_ws.Rows(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 11 to last
If db_ws.Range("A"& i).EntireRowHidden=False Then
    tgt_ws.Range("A"& i).Value = db_ws.Range("A" & i).Value
    tgt_ws.Range("B" & i).Value = db_ws.Range("A" & i).Value
End If
Next i
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I used your link with the array solution in the meanwhile! Both works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

For completion of the topic here you go with the array solution.

```
count = -1 ' array has to start with 0

On Error GoTo errHndlr:
For Each cl In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    count = count + 1
    ReDim Preserve arr(count)
    arr(count) = cl.Row
    Debug.Print cl.Row
Next cl
errHndlr:

For Each Item In arr
    db_ws.Cells(Int(Item), 55) = db_ws.Cells(Int(Item), 1).Value
Next Item
```