# Apply greater than logic to already autofiltered rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have applied the below filter to an excel sheet which autofilters the column O based on start date and end date.

```
sht1.Range("$A$1:$X$3432").AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:= _
        ">=" & CDbl(StartDate), Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & CDbl(EndDate)
```

here I have calculated the visible filtered rows based on start date and end date.

```
With sht1
    Total_DCR = WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(102, ActiveSheet.Range("O1:O5000").Columns(1))
    Debug.Print Total_DCR
End With

Dim i, delay_count As Integer
```

Now I want to compare the dates present in filtered column O and X for greater than logic.If O2 >X2  then increment a counter by 1.

```
For i = 2 To Total_DCR
    If sht1.Range("O" & i).Value > sht1.Range("X" & i).Value Then
    delay_count = delay_count + 1
    Debug.Print delay_count
End If
Next
```

After executing the above comparison code the count of greater than dates from O column is showing wrong data. I feel it is considering the hidden rows as well. In O column there are 79 dates which are between start date and end date. when I opt for greater than logic between filtered O and X for greater than logic using IF(O2>X2,"YES","NO") logic the greater than rows counts to 53.
I want to implement the same using vba code. But I am getting greater than rows count to 76. I dont know what is wrong here. kindly help

Comment: The top two answers to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849177/easiest-way-to-loop-through-a-filtered-list-with-vba) might help you.

Comment: Sorry I am still struck. Tried but getting delay count 0 Dim cl As Range, rng As Range Set rng=Range("$A$1:$X$4000"), For Each cl In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
delay_count = delay_count + IIf(cl.Cells(1, "O") > cl.Cells(1, "X"), 1, 0)
Next cl

Answer (score 0):

You can get the visible cells without header:

```
Sub ZZZ()
    Dim rng As Range, rngVisible As Range, rngRow As Range, delay_count As Double
    Set rng = Range("$A$1:$X$3432")
    '// Get visible cells excluding header
    With rng
        Set rngVisible = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    End With
    '// Must use "Cells" when dealing with "Rows" property
    For Each rngRow In rngVisible.Rows
        delay_count = delay_count + IIf(rngRow.Cells(1, "O") > rngRow.Cells(1, "X"), 1, 0)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: The above code returns me 0 delay count. Col O:actual close date, col X:Required close date. I input from a different excel sheet the start date and end date as 01-02-2020, 29-02-2020. pressing button,Col O and X filters to as per start date and end date. After filter the row index starts from 2780th row. above code should see the visible filtered February month rows of O col and compare it with X col to check weather O date is > than X col date and increment the counter. I am struck here. Please help.

Comment: @beginner Wasn't your concern about processing visible rows namely? This code gets this range - now you can process it any way you need.

Comment: Thank you for the time@JohnL . I have proceeded the way you told but the delay count comes to 0 at the end. Something I am missing which I am unable to find. My concern was comparing visible two autofiltered date columns for greater than operation and increasing counter. Kindly help

Comment: @beginner So, this is what my code is doing: it filters the range and then process visible cells only.

Comment: @beginner Then I would need to see workbook with the real data.

Comment: where can I send to you. details please

Comment: @beginner Send to sektorfl@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim F11, F22, Month, Year As Variant
  Dim f_name1, f_name2
  Dim wb1, wb2, wb3, wb4 As Workbook
  Dim sht1, sht2, sht3, sht4 As Worksheet
  Dim Total_DCR As Long
  Dim StartDate, EndDate As Date

'Select Product Backlog File
 F11 = Application.GetOpenFilename("check (*.xlsm*), *.xlsm*")
  If (F11 <> vbNullString) Then
    If (F11 <> "False") Then
      f_name1 = F11
    End If
  End If
  If (f_name1 = "") Then
    MsgBox "The check file must be specified."
    Exit Sub
  End If

Set wb1 = Excel.Workbooks.Open(f_name1)
Set sht1 = wb1.Sheets("Product Backlog")


Set wb3 = ThisWorkbook
Set sht3 = wb3.Sheets("check")
With sht3

        StartDate = sht3.Range("J3").Value
        'Debug.Print StartDate

        If IsDate(StartDate) = True Then
        MsgBox ("The following string is a valid date expression")
        Else
        'if its not a date expression show a message box
        MsgBox ("The following string is not a valid date expression")
        End If

        EndDate = sht3.Range("J4").Value
        'Debug.Print EndDate

End With

wb1.Activate
sht1.Activate
    sht1.Columns("O:O").Select
    wb1.Worksheets("Product Backlog").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    wb1.Worksheets("Product Backlog").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range( _
        "O1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal

With wb1.Worksheets("Product Backlog").Sort
        .SetRange Range("O1:O3437")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply

End With


sht1.Range("$A$1:$X$3432").AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:= _
        ">=" & CDbl(StartDate), Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & CDbl(EndDate)

With sht1
    Total_DCR = WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(102, ActiveSheet.Range("O1:O5000").Columns(1))
    Debug.Print Total_DCR
End With
 Dim rng As Range, rngVisible As Range, rngRow As Range, delay_count As Double
    Set rng = Range("$A$1:$X$5000")
    '// Get visible cells excluding header
    With rng
        Set rngVisible = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    End With
    '// Must use "Cells" when dealing with "Rows" property
    For Each rngRow In rngVisible.Rows
        delay_count = delay_count + IIf(rngRow.Cells(1, "O") > rngRow.Cells(1, "X"), 1, 0)
    Next
MsgBox ("total delay DCR is" & delay_count)

End Sub
```

@JohnyL this is my whole code. The check work book contains random date from year 2017 to 2020 as per every month in Col O. same way  Col X contains date as well. The code must filter them for February 2020 dates and then compare between O and X dates.
start date:01-02-2020
end date:20-02-2020

All the A-X columns have filter dropdown added. when autofilter is applied it will filter the february 2020 dates only. A-X row is there in first row with headers

@EylM Would you mind answering this