# function for average of visible data on filtered table

Tags: excel, vba, filter, average, visible

```vb
FUNCTION_TABLE_ARRAY_AVERAGE(Rg As Range)
'Trying to get average of filtered cells
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim xCount As integer
    Dim xTtl As variant
    Application.Volatile
    Set Rg = Intersect(Rg.Parent.UsedRange, Rg)
    For Each xCell In Rg
        If xCell.ColumnWidth > 0 _
          And xCell.RowHeight > 0 _
          And Not IsEmpty(xCell) _
          And IsNumeric(xCell.Value) Then
              xTtl = xTtl + xCell.Value
              xCount = xCount + 1
        End If
    Next
    If xCount > 0 Then
        AverVisible = xTtl / xCount
    Else
        AverVisible = 0
    End If
End Function
```

I'm looking to have this function calculate the average of a fraction or decimal or whole number in the
column i select on a filtered table.

Comment: Are you reinventing the `SUBTOTAL` function?

Comment: iv actually never heard of that function if it works ill delete the post

Comment: yeah so i've tried the function and the only thing i dont like is that i have to copy the range by hand. and I would want it to select itself everytime.

Comment: basically. the goal would be to have the filtered column select itself and then calculate the average of the selected range.

Comment: The core of your issue is that you want to iterate through cells that got through a filter.  Check out this post: [Easiest way to loop through a filtered list with VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849177/easiest-way-to-loop-through-a-filtered-list-with-vba)

Comment: @TehDrunkSailor thank you for the link, and would you know an easy way to get this to calculate a different function? that is if I wanted to change it!

Comment: @BryceEisner, The code in the link simply prints the value of the cell to the Immediate window.  Fair enough, it's little more than a template.  What you need to do is replace the line `Debug.Print cl` in the link code with whatever you want to do with each cell.  If you have a specific question on getting that to work, you should ask a new question.